# Registration Form connecting to MySQL with JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm new to JAVA, and trying to build a login and registration form which connected to MySQL local database. I've searched many instructions to connect my JAVA to MySQL, but it ends up with error. I think I have some problem with actionEvent() and actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) methods. I want to make it like when I register a new account, I want to save that user data into MySQL local database. Can someone help me to solve my problem? Here is my JAVA coding.

```
package login_register_form;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.*;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class RegisterPage implements ActionListener{



// frame
JFrame frame;
// Options of position input
String[] position = {"Admin", "Manager", "Assistant"};
// inputs
JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
JTextField userName = new JTextField();
JTextField email = new JTextField();
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
JPasswordField confirmPW = new JPasswordField();
JComboBox positionComboBox = new JComboBox(position);
// labels
JLabel firstnameLabel = new JLabel("First Name");
JLabel lastnameLabel = new JLabel("Last Name");
JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("User Name");
JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
JLabel confirmPWLabel = new JLabel("Re-Password");
JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email");
JLabel positionLabel = new JLabel("Position");
JLabel returnLoginLabel = new JLabel("Return to Login Page");
// buttons
JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
JButton cancelButton  = new JButton("Cancel");


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RegisterPage window = new RegisterPage();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application. Calling methods from constructor
 */
public RegisterPage() {
    createWindow();     
    initialize();
    actionEvent();
    actionPerformed(null);
    
}

/**
 * Create a main window
 */
public void createWindow() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Registration Page");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1113, 806);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    
    
    // panel: orange colored background
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255,165,0,200));
    panel.setBounds(300, 150, 500, 472);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    // label: scaled background 
    JLabel background = new JLabel("");
    background.setBounds(6, 6, 1100, 772);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/background.jpg"));
    Image img = icon.getImage();
    Image imgScale = img.getScaledInstance(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    background.setIcon(scaledIcon);
    frame.getContentPane().add(background);
    
    // title: "Register Page"
    JLabel registerPage = new JLabel("Register Page");
    registerPage.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 19));
    registerPage.setBounds(182, 40, 135, 29);
    panel.add(registerPage);
    
    // input: first name        
    firstName.setBounds(145, 76, 210, 32);
    panel.add(firstName);
    firstName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: last name
    lastName.setBounds(145, 120, 210, 32);
    panel.add(lastName);
    lastName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: user name
    userName.setBounds(145, 164, 210, 32);
    panel.add(userName);
    userName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: password
    password.setBounds(145, 208, 210, 32);
    panel.add(password);
    
    // input: confirm password
    confirmPW.setBounds(145, 252, 210, 32);
    panel.add(confirmPW);
    
    // input: emailLabel
    email.setBounds(145, 296, 210, 32);
    panel.add(email);
    email.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: position
    positionComboBox.setBounds(145, 340, 210, 32);
    panel.add(positionComboBox);
    
    // label: first name
    firstnameLabel.setBounds(36, 84, 85, 16);
    panel.add(firstnameLabel);
    
    // label: last name
    lastnameLabel.setBounds(36, 128, 85, 16);
    panel.add(lastnameLabel);
    
    // label: user name
    usernameLabel.setBounds(36, 172, 85, 16);
    panel.add(usernameLabel);
    
    // label: password
    passwordLabel.setBounds(36, 216, 85, 16);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);
    
    // label: re-password
    confirmPWLabel.setBounds(36, 260, 85, 16);
    panel.add(confirmPWLabel);
    
    // label: emailLabel
    emailLabel.setBounds(36, 304, 85, 16);
    panel.add(emailLabel);
    
    // label: position
    positionLabel.setBounds(36, 347, 101, 16);
    panel.add(positionLabel);
    
    // Label: create a new account
    returnLoginLabel.setBounds(182, 450, 138, 16);
    panel.add(returnLoginLabel);
    returnLoginLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                new LoginPage();
            }
        });
    
    // button: cancel
    cancelButton.setBounds(109, 400, 117, 40);
    panel.add(cancelButton);
            
    // button: register
    registerButton.setBounds(275, 400, 117, 40);
    panel.add(registerButton);
            
}
public void actionEvent() {
    // Adding action listener to buttons
    registerButton.addActionListener(this);
    cancelButton.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == registerButton) {
        try {
            //Creating Connection Object
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root", "root");
            //Prepared Statement
            PreparedStatement Pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            // Specifying the values of it's parameter
            Pstatement.setString(1, firstName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(2, lastName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(3, userName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(4, password.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(5, confirmPW.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(6, email.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(7, positionComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //Checking for the password match
            if (password.getText().equals(confirmPW.getText())) {
                // Executing query
                Pstatement.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Registered Successfully");
                // go back to login page if registered successfully
                frame.setVisible(false);
                new LoginPage();
            } 
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password did not match");
                // Clearing confirm password fields
                confirmPW.setText("");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == cancelButton) {
        // Clearing Fields
        firstName.setText("");
        lastName.setText("");
        userName.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        confirmPW.setText("");
        email.setText("");
        positionComboBox.setSelectedItem("Admin");
    }
}
}
```

Here is my MySQL coding:

```
create database myDatabase;
use myDatabase;
create table user( 
FIRSTNAME varchar(20), 
LASTNAME varchar(20), 
USERNAME varchar(20) not null, 
PASSWRD varchar(20), 
CONFIRMPASSWORD varchar(20),
EMAIL varchar(20),
POSITION varchar(20) );
```

Please tell me, if I'm doing anything wrong. Thank you!

Comment: *"but it ends up with error. "* - What's the error? You should also post the error message and associated stack trace if avaliable

Comment: Don't do `actionPerformed(null)` - this is resulting in a `NullPointerException` - it would be very rare for you ever to need to call this directly yourself

Comment: You're going to dig yourself into very deep hole, very quickly using `setLayout(null)` - you should avoid doing so.  Instead, take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and take some time to understand how to use appropriate layout managers

Comment: I see, thank you for the responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

For the line `("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root", "root")`, you should check if the password is ***root***.  if there is no password, then it should be like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == registerButton) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Creating Connection Object
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root", "");
            //Prepared Statement
            PreparedStatement Pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            // Specifying the values of it's parameter
            Pstatement.setString(1, firstName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(2, lastName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(3, userName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(4, password.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(5, confirmPW.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(6, email.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(7, positionComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //Checking for the password match
            if (password.getText().equals(confirmPW.getText())) {
                // Executing query
                Pstatement.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Registered Successfully");
                // go back to login page if registered successfully
                frame.setVisible(false);
                new LoginPage();
            } 
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password did not match");
                // Clearing confirm password fields
                confirmPW.setText("");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: what does the line: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); works like?
Thank you for the answering! :)

Comment: I added the line: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
and changed the password, but it still doesn’t work..

Comment: The `Class` class is located in the java.lang package, so it is distributed with java, and imported automatically into every class.

What the `forName()` method does, is just return the `Class` object for the paramater that was loaded by the class loader. The `newInstance()` method then returns a new instance of the class.

So then what happens is you call `Class.forName(...)` it returns com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class. You then call `newInstance()` on that class which returns an instance of the class, whith no paramaters, so it's basically calling `new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();`.

Comment: @TSK, Can you tell me if it is displaying any error? because when i run the code, it works fine for me and the table is updated.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for the explanation! 
So, should I add some other line to make it works?
It's still not working after I added the line

Comment: There is no error code for me
After I register a new user, I can't see any user data from Mysql Workbench
Is there anyway to check that?

Comment: @TSK, i used phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I see. What is the difference between MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin? Should I use phpMyAdmin too?

Comment: I didn't think you needed to do this any more - mind you it's been SOOOO long since I had to seriously play around with JDBC :P

Comment: What should I study then? I'm kinda new to JAVA, so is there any trendy  database?